# Embedding a chrome native app into an existing tab with content scripts

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

I am not so certain this is even the right approach. Essentially, I would like to control some WiFi lights (Milight/LimitlessLED brand) so that I can fade out and fade in lights when videos are played on YouTube, Netflix, and other similar services.

The only way to communicate with the lights is by sending UDP messages, and it seems the only way I can access a UDP socket in chrome is either through a chrome app, or a native app.

Native apps seem better, as I can bundle them along with an extension while I don't seem to be able to do that with a chrome app. But in the examples I've seen in documentation, a portable native app (PNaCl), is embedded into a page using `<embed>`.

Well, a content script can create an  tag, but then how could I load the native app without violating the same origin policy? Or would there be a better solution to what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create the embed in a [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages).  Then have your content script eavesdrop on the event that causes the video to start playing, have it send a [message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the background script.  Then the background script can control the embed by triggering appropriate events.

Comment: Deleted previous comment, hit enter too soon.

I feel the chrome documentation a bit lacking in this regard.

It seems Chrome extensions do not have access to the entirety of the Chrome API such as network stack. Chrome Apps however do.

Chrome extensions can make HTTP requests, can launch apps, and can message apps directly using [an internal messaging component](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

So I think my approach in the end is a Chrome App that acts as HTTP Server and extension to send AJAX requests to it.

Comment: @AlexDowgailenko Chrome Apps can use Native Messaging just as well.